# Ubuntu recognising RAID 0 array as multiple disks

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, raid, mount

I have two rather old USBs lying around, and so I decided to experiment with BTRFS on them. Today I decided to try BTRFS' native software RAID, by formatting them together using the following command:

```
mkfs.btrfs -m raid0 -d raid0 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc -f
```

However, when I mounted the disks (`mount /dev/sdb <mountpoint>`) I found that Nautilus was showing both USBs individually:

[image]
'4.0 GB Volume' and '8.0 GB Volume' are supposed to be shown as a single drive, as that's how they are mounted.

Worse yet, when I click on either drive, Nautilus mounts that disk again to a different mountpoint. At first, when I didn't know what was going on, I managed to accidentally mount each drive on around 20 mountpoints each...

When using the terminal, I have been able to mount the disks as a single volume and copy data to them too (the data is striped, as expected)

Why is Nautilus behaving like this? Surely, it must be familiar with BTRFS disks?